# Ruby/Rails dictionary app - 6 letter words finder that are built of two concatenated smaller words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create functionality which is going to process the dictionary (dictionary.txt file). The goal is to find all six-letter words that are built of two concatenated smaller words e.g.:

```
con + vex => convex
tail + or => tailor
we + aver => weaver
```

Of course, there may be some words inside the file that are not 6 letters long, but these can be easily sifted out using a simple method:

```
def cleanup_file
  file_data = File.read('dictrionary.txt').split

  file_data.reject! { |word| word.size < 6 }
end
```

But now comes the problem - how to find if the other strings in the array are made of two connected smaller words ?

[Edit]

Sample dictionary.txt file [here](https://easyupload.io/tbni29)

Comment: So what issue are you having specifically?  What have you tried to accomplish this with so far that is not working or you need help debugging?  Can you share the code that is giving you issues related to this?

Comment: @RockwellRice Unfortunately, this is not the type of issue. I don't know how to even start the implementation. At this point, all I have in mind is to use some external API to download all the 6 letter words and check the strings in the dictionary.txt file (or the `file_data`), one by one, to see if they match. So as you see, even a simple tip will be helpful, I just don't know how to start.

Comment: Are you given an array of words such as`arr = ['con', 'vex', 'tail', 'or', 'we', 'aver',  'mouse', 'a']` and given a six-letter word in the text you want to know if `arr` can be formed by concatenating two elements of `arr`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland All I have is the sample `dictionary.txt` (I have edited the post to include a sample file) and a command that says: `find all six-letter words that are built of two concatenated smaller words`

Comment: Ah! You wish to find all six-letters words in the dictionary that can be formed by concatenating two other words *in the dictionary*.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking just in a pseudo code solution, but you should:

- Iterate every line of the dictionary and store the words in 6 different arrays by the length of each word.

  - Make sure that all words are [downcased](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-downcase), there are no [duplicates](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) and all the values are [sorted](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-sort), so later you could properly use [`.bsearch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) in the arrays.
- Iterate the length-6 array (for example `convex`) and look for a match of the first character of the current word in the length-1 array (`c` for the given example) and in the length-5 array (`onvex`). If there's a match, save the words.

  - Then keep looking in the length-2 and length-4 arrays for matches (`co` and `nvex` correspondingly) and save a match.
  - Finally, look both parts of the string in the length-3 array (`con` and `vex`) and save any match
  - Look for the next 6 characters string until you've finished.

Most likely there are better ways to solve this, like in the first iteration inserting each word in its corresponding array using [`.bsearch_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) to sort and not inserting duplicates in the same iteration, but most of the workload is going to be in the 2nd iteration and binary searches work in `O(log n)` time, so I guess it should work quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the dictionary is as follows.

```
dictionary = [
  "a", "abased", "act", "action", "animal", "ape", "apeman",
  "art", "assertion", "bar", "barbed", "barhop", "based", "be",
  "become", "bed", "come", "hop", "ion", "man"
]
```

I assume that, like most dictionaries, `dictionary` is sorted.

First compute the following hash.

```
by_len = dictionary.each_with_object({}) do |w,h|
  len = w.length
  (h[len] ||= []) << w if len < 7
end    
  #=> {1=>["a"],
  #    6=>["abased", "action", "animal", "apeman", "barbed",
  #        "barhop", "become"],
  #    3=>["act", "ape", "art", "bar", "bed", "hop", "ion", "man"],
  #    5=>["based"],
  #    2=>["be"],
  #    4=>["come"]}
```

Each key is a word length (1-6) and each value is an array of words from `dictionary` whose length is the value of the key.

Next I will define a helper function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether a given array of words (`list`) contains a given word (`word`).

```
def found?(list, word)
  w = list.bsearch { |w| w >= word }
  w && w == word
end
```

For example:

```
found?(by_len[3], "art")
  #=> true
found?(by_len[3], "any")
  #=> false
```

See [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

We now extract the words of interest:

```
by_len[6].select { |w| (1..5).any? { |i|
  found?(by_len[i], w[0,i]) && found?(by_len[6-i], w[i..-1]) } }
  #=> ["abased", "action", "apeman", "barbed", "barhop", "become"]
```

Comment: What does this code `{ |w| (1..5).any?` actually check?

Comment: When `i = 1` it checks whether there are words of length `1` and `6-1 = 5` which, when concatenated, form the word held by the variable `w`. When `i=2` it checks whether there are words of length `2` and `6-2 = 4` that form the word held by the variable `w`, and so on. Since `any?` is used the checks for the word held by `w` terminate as soon as a match is found.

Comment: Is there any way to break this into two separate steps?

Comment: And one more question - is this necessary `w && w == word` ? I mean `w == word` won't be enough?

Comment: Mr. Muscle, `found?(by_len[i], w[0,i])` is `true` if a word of length `i` is found that equals the first `i` characters of `w`. If such a word is found `found?(by_len[6-i], w[i..-1])` determines if a word of length `6-i` is found that equals the last `6-i` characters of `w`. If no match is made of the first `i` characters of `w`, `found?(by_len[6-i], w[i..-1])` is not executed. Does that answer your questions.